# Terminal unavailable in Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I installed Jupyter notebook with Python 3, It works fine and I point to my python3 from the **New**. Then I close it and when I open it again the option **terminal** is changed to **Terminal unavailable** and **python3** is appeared as **python[root]**. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This link says it's because windows does not have TTY-based terminal support

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/172